# How do I compute $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+2)7^n} $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to evaluate the following sum:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+2)7^n} $$

Probably the best way to do that is to try and find a closed formula for

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(n+2)x^n} $$

Probably it requires some integrating/differentiating. I've tried both, but I can't get it to look any more decently.

I'd appreciate some hint

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+2)7^n}=49\int_{0}^{1/7}\sum_{n\geq 0}x^{n+1}\,dx = 49\int_{0}^{1/7}\frac{x}{1-x}\,dx = \color{red}{-7+49\log\frac{7}{6}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This Taylor series should help you: $$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}, \ \ |x| < 1$$